# Find three events that are dependent but pairwise independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ denote the probability triple for the discrete uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

**Q.** Give an example of three dependent events with probabilities strictly between **$0$** and **$1$**, that are pairwise independent.

---

so My logic on this is something like a spinner with equal chances for all 4 and then if you get a certain number you flip a coin or something

I just am confused on how they can be pairwise independent but then dependent combined u no

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example. Consider binary random variables:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 \omega & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
 \hline
 X_1(\omega) & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \hline 
 X_2(\omega) & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 X_3(\omega) = X_1(\omega) + X_2(\omega) \; \text{mod} \;2 &
 0 & 1 & 1& 0
\end{array}

It is not hard to see that these three are pariwise independent. For example, if I know $X_1 = 1$, it is equally likely that either of $X_2$ or $X_3$ are 0 or 1, and similarly for the other cases. However, they are not mutually independent, since given $X_1$ and $X_2$, $X_3$ is completely determined (whereas unconditionally it is not.)

This by the way is the classical example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example[image]

Here A,B,C are pairwise independent but all three together are not mutually independent.

Another example

Suppose two independent dice, one blue and one red, are rolled.
Let A be the event that the face on the blue die is even,
B the event that the face on the red die is even,
and C the event that sum of the two faces is even.

Comment: Hi ethanol, Thanks.

I guess would this mean I'm on the right track?

A is the event you get less than 3.    A={1,2} P(A)=1/2
B is the event you get an even number  B={2,4} P(B)=1/2
C is the event you get a 2 or 3.       C={2,3}, P(C)=1/2  

Then if this is the case you test the probability between two happening (which in this case will all equal 1/4) and make sure they're independent by multiplying the individual ones together and see if they're equal. 

Then once that is done, show that all 3 can't be independent!?

Comment: @BillyZAAAANE Your example is correct. A,B,C are pairwise independent in your example but not mutually independent.